# Compile Node.js for Raspberry fast

Tags: compiling, node.js

I wan't to know if there is a faster way to compile the node.js code for raspberry then letting the raspberry itself compile the code.

Assuming I have cloned the nodejs source into  */home/pi/node/* on my raspberry.

1. Is it right to run the `./configure` on the raspberry.
2. Then copy the node folder to my desktop computer and run `make`.
3. Then copy the folder back to my raspberry */home/pi/node* and run `make install`.

Would that work and if yes, are there any downsides to this method?

---

**EDIT:** I accepted to use the [precompiled](http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/) Version suggested by [goldilocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/25985/goldilocks) as it is truly the fastest way of getting the newest node asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is that you don't do this and instead use [a precompiled version](http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/).

However, if that's not good enough:

> Is it right to run the ./configure on the raspberry?

Yes.

> Then copy the node folder to my desktop computer and run make.

No. The build must be done natively on the pi, or else with the use of a cross compiler.  In the former case, resolving dependencies will be easy since you can just install them w/ `apt-get`, but the build will be SLOW.  In the latter case, the build will probably be much much faster (presuming your desktop is not also a 700 Mhz single core), but getting it set up and resolving dependencies in the cross environment will probably take you a lot of time to learn and is more prone to error -- including the possibility of subtle flaws in the executable.

> run `make install`

The default install directory is probably `/usr/local`, so you should do that step as root (I don't know how well `sudo make ...` works), or else set `INSTALL_DIR` -- `./configure --help` should provide some information about this.

Comment: Hat tip to you sir! Saved me a lot of time. Precompiled... i should have thought about that by myself :)